# Position Menu Icon inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble positioning Menu Icon inside div. I am using Responsive full overlay navigation menu from https://navnav.co/ .
I am using this in my personal website but the menu icon is always at top-right of the page. 
What i am trying to do is, when my website loads, i am displaying a full cover wallpaper. 
and after scrolling down i have a navigation menu after the wallpaper ends.

I want to put that menu icon in that div only and not in top right of webpage.

```
.cd-nav-trigger {
      /* hamburger icon */
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 3;
      top: 12px;
      right: 5%;
      height: 44px;
      width: 44px;
      /* image replacement */
      overflow: hidden;
      text-indent: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
    }
```

I have created a demo jsfiddle please check it. Its just a prototype.
https://jsfiddle.net/szn0007/zwds84ec/

Please also refer the screenshots.
[image: I dont want menu icon here.]
[image: I want menu icon to be here all the time.even when i scroll.]

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, remove the `position` attribute

```
.cd-nav-trigger {
    /*position: fixed;*/
}
```

This will position your menu icon wrt the menu container. `position: fixed` positions it wrt the page

Comment: No it didnot help :(

Comment: @SujanShrestha can you then explain clearly what you want

Comment: I am making a website with front load page as a full cover photo as shown in the first picture. After scrolling down there is the navigation menu as shown in second pic. I want that menu icon always in the div with class menu-icon.
Not in the picture as shown in the first picture.